# SAX parser not completely working inside swing worker thread

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, swingworker

I tried everything but couldn't get it working:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground()
    throws Exception
{
    // This code uses the online stream and parse the xml.
    class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler
    {
        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException
        {
            System.out.println(qName);

            switch (qName) {
                case "requiredName":
                // Code to create new node
                break ;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException
        {
            content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) 
            throws SAXException
        {
            System.out.println("---" + qName + "---");

            switch (qName) {
                case "closing tag":
                    publish(object);
            }
        }
    }

    URL url = new URL("http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/infogate");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.connect();
    InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();
    SAXParserFactory spfac = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

    SAXParser parser = spfac.newSAXParser();
    SaxHandler handler = new SaxHandler();
    System.out.println("I am here");
    parser.parse(stream, handler);
}
```

For testing purposes, I just want that the parser writes out all the tags name it encounters while parsing the XML. But it only writes some starting tags and then it does not parse more.

If you go to the [XML Page](http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/infogate) and view its source then you will be able to see the tags. It is only parsing some tags of the starting line up to the first `<title>` tag.

**Update:** The code for parsing is working fine in a separate class but not working when written inside the Swing worker thread's `doInBackground()` method.

Everything else in my application is ready and I am stuck on this part.

Comment: Several comments here: `new InputStreamReader(oConnection.getInputStream())` -- this uses your default charset, not charset from XML. This can break your XML document when saving it to file. To be safe, just copy input stream to output stream, without any conversion to characters. What output do you get from those two approaches? any exception?

Comment: @PeterŠtibraný the file is properly downloaded without any problem in the charset. Both my approaches provided the same result, i.e., the parser could not parse more than the `<titlt>` tag

Comment: I tried your code (second method) and it worked well. All xml tagnames are printed out. - please post the complete java files. I assume there might be something wrong with your imports.

Comment: @azraelAT you are right, i wrote the code in a separate file and its working. The problem is occurring when i am trying to do the same thing inside a swing worker thread. Now i think, i should modify the question.

Comment: How are you starting the `SwingWorker`? I find that most Swing code needs to be run through the Event Dispath Thread (`EDT`) using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` like this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: Is it possible that your worker throws exception, but you don't see it, because you don't call worker.get() method (which would return that exception wrapped into ExecutionException)? What does worker.isDone() return?